# Отвечая забаненным(,) ты подвергаешь себя риску составить им компанию

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

***Отвечая забаненным, ты подвергаешь себя риску составить им компанию.***

Вынужденно написал с запятой, которая мне здесь совсем не по душе.
Есть ли хоть малейшие основания свести этот случай к деепричастию, неразрывно связанному со сказуемым (там обычно идет речь только об одиночном деепричастии) или чему-то подобному?

Answer (score 2):

Деепричастный оборот не обособляется, если он **непосредственно примыкает** к глаголу и имеет значение образа действия:
*Старик шёл  прихрамывая на правую ногу* (шёл — *как? каким образом?* — прихрамывая).

В Вашем предложении между деепричастием и глаголом находятся другие члены предложения, поэтому оборот обособляется на общих основаниях.

*[Ты реагируешь — значит, он тебе небезразличен, а это пусть и негативный, но хоть какой-то эффект.] Отвечая ему тем же, ты рискуешь стать похожим на него* (из статьи).

*Отвечая ее мыслям, Мартов обнял ее, закрыв глаза* (Н. Рощина. Призрак счастья).

*Рассказав ей, ты рискуешь всем* (М. Макфи. Благородный разбойник).

[Деепричастные обороты, которые не обособляются](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=196)

Comment: *Деепричастный оборот не обособляется, если он непосредственно примыкает к глаголу и имеет значение образа действия* - ээээ.... А откуда такая формулировка вообще?! Про ***деепричастный оборот***? И у Р. и у Л. речь идет только ***об одиночном деепричастии***.

Comment: А вот что касается вашего примера про старика, там у Р. совсем другое основание: *если деепричастный оборот (обычно со значением обстоятельства образа действия) тесно связан по содержанию со сказуемым и образует смысловой центр высказывания*. И тут нету про примыкание. Другое дело, что к моему случаю тут все равно трудно мостик перекинуть.

Comment: Спасибо за оценку. У Лопатина: Такие деепричастия по функции сближаются с наречием: _Это упражнение делают **сидя на стуле._** P. S. Позволила себе подправить Ваш вопрос — всё ли правильно?

Comment: Насчет правки - да, спасибо. Насчет Лопатина. У него тоже речь идет об ***одиночных*** деепричастиях. Хотя пример этому противоречит. Но я гляну сейчас.

Comment: В общем понятно. Судя по всему, Лопатин, хоть и  говорит о "примыкающем" деепричастии, но не исключает случай, когда это деепричастие находится в составе деепричастного оборота. Так что тут вы правы, Лопатин по сравнению с Розенталем дает некую новацию. Но мне это, как вы тоже верно говорите, с исходным примеров не поможет. Завтра, на свежую голову, я тогда вопрос разовью.

Answer (score 0):

Никаких оснований. Отбросим оборот - предложение имеет тот же смысл, что и без него.
Ср. *Она сидела откинув голову*. Вот пример тесной связи со сказуемым. Попробуйте-ка здесь отбросить оборот.

Comment: Во-первых, смысл будет другой. А во-вторых, подобный прием нигде не описан как критерий. Да, и в-третьих, я совсем не настаиваю, что "тесная связь со сказуемым" - единственное основание. У Розенталя много всяких случаев перечислено, тесная связь - только один из них.

Comment: И ни один случай не подходит, чтобы не обособлять. Обычный деепричастный оборот, обособляется на общих основаниях.