# Имярек(,) хоть и говорит об одном, но не исключает другого

Tags: синтаксис

*Что-то меня на запятые сегоднодня пробило... Говорили об одной запятой, а встал в тупик по поводу совсем другой.*

Вот точная фраза, написанная мной в комментариях к вопросу  [Отвечая забаненным(,) ты подвергаешь себя риску составить им компанию](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/444771) .

***Лопатин(,) хоть и  говорит о "примыкающем" деепричастии, но не исключает случай, когда это деепричастие находится в составе деепричастного оборота.***

Здесь, напротив, не могу без запятой на эту фразу смотреть. Но совершенно не вижу, на каком основании её поставить - да еще между подлежащим и сказуемым. Или тут вообще другая грамматика?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет оснований.

> **ХОТЬ / ХОТЯ (И) … А / ДА / НО**, союз
>
> Запятая ставится перед второй частью союза (перед «а / да / но»).
>
> *В избе хоть и скверно пахнет, да тепло, по крайней мере...* И.
>   Гончаров, Обломов. *Да, он все знает, все понимает и этими словами
>   говорит мне, что хотя и стыдно, а надо пережить свой стыд.* Л. Толстой,
>   Анна Каренина. ***Жизнь хотя и тяжелая, но не в пример.*** А. и Б.
>   Стругацкие, Град обреченный.

Источник: [справочник по пунктуации на Грамоте.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_749).

Comment: Да я знаю, что этот союз пишется с запятой перед но. А вот как передать паузу перед "хотя"?! Примеры ваши ("Грамоты") сомнений у меня не вызывают. Я не настаиваю на "своей" запятой, тут какая-то особая интонация, которую хочется передать на письме... Ладно, наверное это действительно невозможно.

Comment: @behemothus Я посмотрел пару десятков цитат в авторитетных источниках. Пауза бывает от почти нулевой до максимальной, но запятых нет. Пример из Плунгяна: "А беглец и бегун хотя и занимаются оба бегом, но с совершенно разными целями". Вот здесь пауза мне слышится даже больше (из-за союза в начале), но вот тоже.

Answer (score 1):

Если союз НО убрать, то запятая ставится. И "между подлежащим и сказуемым" тут ни при чём, не путаем обособление и разделение.